# How can I make a private member object-encapsulated?

Tags: scala, clojure, f#, erlang

In Scala by typing `private[this]` we can make a private member *only accessible by that particular object* of the class, and *another object of the same class cannot access it*. If possible, how can we accomplish this in other languages... particularly F#, Erlang, and Clojure?

Comment: This is definitely possible in F# and I would assume so in the others as well

Comment: How so? Can you provide an example? I can't find anything from searching

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/members/methods

Comment: Not to try to give with an excuse for not coming up with an answer, but why do you need to do this? I've thought about this a lot, and so far, I've ended up agreeing with [Rich Hickey's position](http://clojure.org/reference/datatypes#_datatypes_and_protocols_are_opinionated); I haven't been able to find a situation where data encapsulation provides real benefits in the way that immutability does.

Comment: @JohnPalmer The OP asks for a specifier that would limit access to a member to `this` (and not the declaring type), which is not available in .NET

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are asking about is basically the difference between *Object-Oriented Data Abstraction* and Data Abstraction with *Abstract Data Types* (*ADT*s, not to be confused with Algebraic Data Types, which are also often abbreviated as "ADT"). (See [*On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited*](http://CS.UTexas.Edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) by [William R. Cook](http://WCook.BlogSpot.Com/), his [*Proposal for Simplified, Modern Definitions of "Object" and "Object Oriented"*](http://WCook.BlogSpot.Com/2012/07/proposal-for-simplified-modern.html), and [*Object-Oriented Programming Versus Abstract Data Types*](http://CS.UTexas.Edu/~wcook/papers/OOPvsADT/CookOOPvsADT90.pdf).)

Two different instances of the same Abstract Data Type *can* inspect each other's representation (but not the representation of instances of *other* Abstract Data Types), whereas an object can *never* inspect another object's representation, even if the object is an instance of the *same* type. Cook identifies this property as the fundamental and defining characteristic of Object-Oriented Data Abstraction (and in fact Object-Orientation in general), and calls it *Autognosis* (Self-Knowledge). I prefer the term *Xenoagnosis* (Foreign-Not-Knowledge), which was applied by either Glenn Vanderburg, Rick de Natale, or the late Jim Weirich, IIRC, because it emphasizes the difference between the two approaches, namely that objects cannot know about other objects.

In Scala, as you noticed, Object-Oriented Data Abstraction can be achieved via the `private[this]` access modifier.

```scala
class TestPrivate {
  private       val notReallyPrivate = 42
  private[this] val privateIMeanIt   = 23

  def blowUp(other: TestPrivate) = {
    other.notReallyPrivate
    other.privateIMeanIt
  }
}
// error: value privateIMeanIt is not a member of TestPrivate
```

In Erlang, the equivalent to an Object is a Process, and Processes are fully encapsulated by the language semantics (they even have their own garbage-collected memory). They can even live on a different machine on a different continent, after all, so exposing representation is simply impractical. You send a message to a Process, and the Process is completely autonomous in its decision what to do with the message and how to respond to it. *Everything* is `private[this]`, basically.

In Clojure, Object-Oriented Data Abstraction can be achieved via Closures. (This is true for pretty much any language with closures and higher-order subroutines, e.g. you can also use Functions as Objects in Erlang instead of Processes.) Think about ECMAScript: even though it confusingly has a language construct called "object", in ECMAScript Objects are actually implemented with Functions. You can implement them in Clojure the same way. The Object-Oriented Form of Data Abstraction is also called Procedural Data Abstraction, because instead of relying on Types, it relies on hiding the Data behind a Procedural Interface (or a Functional Interface, if you want, after all, Mutability and Side-Effects are orthogonal to OO). Cook argues (half-jokingly) that because λ-calculus has only functions, all abstraction is functional, and therefore λ-calculus is the first, oldest, and purest OO language – obviously this means that OO Data Abstraction must be possible in languages closely based on λ-calculus such as the Lisp family. (Historical anecdote: Scheme was originally designed to study OO and Actors, they only noticed during the implementation that the code paths of the interpreter for message sending and function calling were identical.)

In languages like Java or C♯, Object-Orientation is achieved using the Type System and Programmer Discipline, by only using `interface`s as Types. `interface`s cannot describe representation, therefore, as long as you make sure (through Programmer Discipline, Coding Styles, Code Reviews, maybe Static Analysis Tools) that only `interface`s are ever used as Types (every local variable, field, method parameter, method return value, cast operator, `instanceof` check, and Generic Type Argument must *always* be an `interface`) and `class`es are *only* used as Factories (the only place where a class name is allowed to appear is directly next to the `new` keyword), then you have achieved Object-Oriented Data Abstraction. (There are some other caveats, most importantly that you must not use Reference Equality.)

```java
interface ITestPrivate {
  default int thisIsPublic() { return 0; }

  default void blowUp1(ITestPrivate other) {
    other.thisIsPublic();
    other.privateIMeanIt();
  }
}

class TestPrivate implements ITestPrivate {
  private int privateIMeanIt() { return 23; }

  void blowUp2(TestPrivate other1, ITestPrivate other2) {
    other1.notReallyPrivate(); // works
    other2.notReallyPrivate(); // doesn't
  }
}
```

Doing this *should* also be possible in F♯, since [F♯ supports `interface`s as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/interfaces).

Comment: BTW: if someone who is more familiar with Erlang, Clojure, F♯, or Java wants to supply/improve examples, go ahead!

Comment: One comment I'd add to this excellent answer and @SamEstep's comment on the question: Often when one wants to restrict access to a "member" variable inside an object or a closure, the purpose is to restrict the ability to change the value of the variable.  Because Clojure is designed for functional programming, as a general rule the value of a variable *can never be changed* once defined.  That reduces the motivation to hide access to a variable.  (It is possible to give a variable a special value, e.g. using `atom`, that indirectly allows changing values, but that requires extra steps.)

Answer (score 3):

F# has `public`, `internal` and `private` [access control specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/access-control). Scalas more restrictive `private[this]` which limits access to *an instance of a type and not the type itself* is not available as a specifier, so even `private` (most restrictive in F#) members of an`other` instance can be accessed. [class `let` bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/members/let-bindings-in-classes) are instance-private though:

```
type Foo(x) =
    let totallyPrivate = x
    member private(*[this]*) __.Bar = x
    member this.Baz (other : Foo) =
        // other.Bar not accessible in Scala
        this.Bar + other.Bar + totallyPrivate
        // the field, constructor or member 'totallyPrivate' is not defined
        // other.totallyPrivate
```

Comment: I think prob you're right, I was actually wondering what exactly the OP had in mind, and threw out the answer as more of a test. It would obviously be more helpful to see a more concrete example (exactly like yours) in the OP.

Comment: You can use a `let` binding in the class instead, which achieves exactly what the OP desires (and the form of the binding indicates this, since it's not bound as a member of the type).

Comment: @kvb thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by my comment on @JörgWMittag's answer, I tend to agree with @SamEstep's comment that what you want to do, codingXeno, would rarely make sense in Clojure.  It's a nice exercise, though, in Common Lisp or Scheme, and is only slightly harder in Clojure.  Here's a very simple illustration of something like what you requested:

```
(def getit-and-setit (let [x (atom 42)]
                       [(fn [] @x), (fn [new-x] (reset! x new-x))]))
```

Here we defined a local variable `x` whose value is an "atom", i.e. something that will hold a value that can be replaced with a new value.  (The contents of an atom can be extracted using `@` or `deref`.  It can be replaced using `reset!` or some other useful operators.)  Then we return a two-element vector.  Each element is a function.  (The comma is not usually used, but it's allowed and made this code clearer.)

```
(def get-it (first getit-and-setit))
(def set-it! (second getit-and-setit))
```

Here extracted the first function and defined a new variable `get-it` to have the function as its value.  And we defined `set-it!` to have the other function as its value.

`get-it` returns the contents of the atom that's the value of `x`:

```
(get-it) ;==> 42
```

`set-it!` replaces the contents of the atom with a new value:

```
(set-it! 5)
(get-it) ;==> 5
```

There are no ways to access `x` other than through `get-it` and `set-it!`.  `x` is "private".

The reason this would be simpler in Common Lisp or Scheme is that in these languages normal local variables can be given new values.  Clojure doesn't allow that, usually.  (There are ways to change the values of variables without using atoms in Clojure if you use Java or Javascript interop methods.  However, this is the sort of thing that you should only do for the sake of interop or for some other special need.)

On the other hand, if you wanted to restrict access to components of a Clojure `defrecord` structure, I don't think you can do that, except by using a method like the one given above.  You can do it with related `deftype` data structure, but that's usually used for Java interop.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to @JohnPalmer's comment and also [Access Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/access-control). Which can be easily found with [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=F%23+private+member/).

```
type  TestPrivate(x)  =
    let y = x - 10
    member private __.X() = 10
    member __.Z() = x + 10
    member __.Y = __.X()

let test = TestPrivate(5)
test.Z() //val it : int = 15
test.Y //val it : int = 10
test.X()
```

> error FS0491: The member or object constructor 'X' is not accessible.
>   Private members may only be accessed from wit hin the declaring type.
>   Protected members may only be accessed from an extending type and
>   cannot be accessed from inner lambda express ions.

**Edit**

```
type TestPrivate(x:string)  =
    let totallyPrivate = x 
    member private __.PrivateX = x
    member __.FromOther(other:TestPrivate) = 
        __.PrivateX + "-" + other.Y + "-" + other.PrivateX + "-" + totallyPrivate
    member __.Y = __.PrivateX

let thisTest = TestPrivate("this")
let otherTest = TestPrivate("other")

thisTest.FromOther(otherTest) //val it : string = "this-other-other-this"
otherTest.FromOther(thisTest) //val it : string = "other-this-this-other"
thisTest.FromOther(thisTest) //val it : string = "this-this-this-this"
otherTest.FromOther(otherTest) //val it : string = "other-other-other-other"
```

So the `this` instance can of course access totallyPrivate, but neither `this` or `other` can access the other's let binding, although they can get at the other's private property.

Comment: This is not what the OP asks for, access restriction to *instances* (not types) are not available in .NET

Comment: Btw: your snotty link to Google is not appropriate, because reading the question would have pointed out: *... and another object of the same class cannot access it ...*

Comment: @CaringDev - that's true; however, the `let` binding actually does demonstrate what the OP asks for: no other instances can use the bound name to access that value.

Comment: So if I do let test2 = TestPrivate(5) will I be unable to access the let binding inside the type?

Comment: @codingXeno test1 can access `x`, it won't be able to access test2's `x`. I will update the answer based on CaringDev's example. Please feel free to expand on it in the OP in case this is not what you were looking for.